# How to order in chain in data.table in r?

Tags: r, data.table

I just came across **data.table** & trying it for first time to benchmark my existing `dplyr` codes to see if they make any difference in time execution and if so then will start learning `data.table`

Have attempted few code in **data.table** but **failed to replicate** the **dplyr** results.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)


df_ind_stacked_daily <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/df_ind_stacked_daily.csv")) %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>% data.table()
```

**data.table** code attempt :

```
df_ind_stacked_daily[Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed" &
                     Date >= max(Date) - 6 & Date <= max(Date) &
                    State.UnionTerritory != "India",
                    by = Date] %>%

  .[order(-Daily_cases_counts),
    .SD[1],
    by = Date]
```

**dplyr code:**

```
 df_ind_stacked_daily %>% as_tibble() %>% 
    filter(Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed",
           Date >= max(Date) - 6 & Date <= max(Date),
           State.UnionTerritory != "India"
    ) %>%
    
    group_by( Date) %>%
    slice_max(order_by = Daily_cases_counts, n = 10) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

Appreciate any help !!

Comment: For future questions, please learn how to create _minimal, self-contained_ examples.

Comment: @Henrik, Sure will keep that in mind. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` translation:

```
df_ind_stacked_daily[Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed" &
                     Date >= max(Date) - 6 & Date <= max(Date) &
                     State.UnionTerritory != "India"
                     ][order(Daily_cases_counts, decreasing = TRUE)
                       ][, .SD[1:10], by = Date]
```

Your main mistake is using `by` incorrectly. It only makes sense in conjunction with `J` (the second argument).

PS. If you'll learn `data.table` the main time saving will come in human time from more concise and (arguably) logical syntax.

Comment: Thanks @sindri_baldur,. I thought I can probably speed up some data processing in `shiny` app using `data.table` specially if the dataset gets large but after your comment I will think again or will probably test with bigger datasets as well. Thanks again, appreciate ur help !!

Answer (score 2):

To demonstrate [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)'s capabilities, I have further streamlined [OP's code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68860037/3817004) and [sindri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68860287/3817004):

```
library(data.table)
fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/df_ind_stacked_daily.csv")[
  Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed" & Date >= max(Date) - 6 & State.UnionTerritory != "India"][
      order(-Daily_cases_counts), head(.SD, 10L), by = Date]
```

1. data.table's fast `fread()` is used to read the data directly from the given *URL*.
2. Column `Date` is automatically coerced to integer date class `IDate` by `fread()` while loading the data. No explicit conversion step is required.
3. The filter condition `Date <= max(Date)` is removed as it is fulfilled for all dates.
4. `order(Daily_cases_counts, decreasing = TRUE)` is replaced by its equivalent
   `order(-Daily_cases_counts)`. Note the minus sign to indicate
   decreasing order.
5. Ordering and grouping is collapsed into one expression.
6. `head(.SD, 10L)` is used as an alternative to `.SD[1:10]`.
7. *data.table chaining* is used throughout which consequentially removes variable `df_ind_stacked_daily`.

Comment: Thanks @Uwe for sharing this highly optimized code. Really appreciate 'ur effort for putting all the explanation along with the code.